# Update Document Library columns

Tags: document-library, web-services

How to update column values in Document Library while creating documents or after creating?

I am adding a new document using the Copy web service. I tried using the Lists web service and Event receiver to update created by, modified by and version columns. But it shows error..

> 0x81020030The URL 'DocLib/DocName' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.